# Do I need any permissions for my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am making my first ever chrome extension and I had some questions. My chrome extension is super simple only containing some buttons that go to links. I want to know if I need any permissions for this sort of thing. I am not collecting data or anything like that, I am only giving the user buttons that they can click to go to different URLs.

[Picture of my extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDu61.jpg)

`"permissions": ["ANYTHING", "ANYTHING"],`
Do I need anything in here?
If not, can I just delete this whole line?

Comment: Just delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly you will not need this line because you did not access any unauthorized user permissions such as access to the camera, file manager, search history, change the browser's background itself, privacy and follow everything ....

But you are only dealing with a simple HTML page DOM

If you want to know every time do you need permissions or not
Just write your code without asking for permissions, and if it works successfully, you do not need access permission, but if the code does not work, then know that you need permission and review the code that's all

You can also find out what powers you can access in your Google Chrome extension

[Declare permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm super new to all this and I didn't want to require any permissions I didn't need!